# QSS not applied to first QSizeGrip in (composite widget) in QVBoxLayout

Tags: python, pyside, qtstylesheets, pyside2

As shown below, the widget `TestWidget` contains a `QFrame` and a CSS-styled `QSizeGrip`. Several `TestWidget` instances are placed in a `QVBoxLayout`

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class TestWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self , parent=None):
        super(TestWidget , self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins( 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 )

        frame = QtGui.QFrame()
        frame.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        frame.setMinimumHeight( 100 )

        grip = QtGui.QSizeGrip(self)
        grip.setStyleSheet( "QSizeGrip { image: url(dots.png); }")
        grip.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.SplitVCursor)

        layout.addWidget(frame)
        layout.addWidget( grip , 0 , QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignRight )

        self.setLayout(layout)

class TestApp(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(parent)

        track1 = TestWidget()
        track2 = TestWidget()
        track3 = TestWidget()

        centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(centralWidget)

        layout.addWidget(track1)
        layout.addWidget(track2)
        layout.addWidget(track3)

        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.show() 

if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = TestApp();
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As shown below, the size grip of the first `TestWidget` in the `QVBoxLayout` appears only if the `TestWidget` is the only element in the layout.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Qt version 4.8.7

PySide version 1.2.2

---

The PySide2 version of the program (below) has the same issue

```
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget , QMainWindow , QGraphicsView , QVBoxLayout , QFrame , QSizeGrip , QWidget

import sys

class TestWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self , parent=None):
        super(TestWidget , self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins( 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 )

        frame = QFrame()
        frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        frame.setMinimumHeight( 100 )

        grip = QSizeGrip(self)
        grip.setStyleSheet( "QSizeGrip { image: url(dots.png); }")
        grip.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.SplitVCursor)

        layout.addWidget(frame)
        layout.addWidget( grip , 0 , QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignRight )

        self.setLayout(layout)

class TestApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(parent)

        track1 = TestWidget()
        track2 = TestWidget()
        track3 = TestWidget()

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(centralWidget)

        layout.addWidget(track1)
        layout.addWidget(track2)
        layout.addWidget(track3)

        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.show() 

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = TestApp();
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

PySide2 version 5.12.1

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry I've been swamped lately. 
BTW I have reported this as a PySide/PySide2 bug
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-978

Comment: But it's not a bug, the bug is that behavior is not documented

Comment: @eyllanesc I see what you mean.The behavior is coded for, but IMO it violates the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)

Comment: Okay, under that principle the report should be in Qt, not in PySide2. :-)

Comment: This issue has been flagged as a Qt bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is observed is a predetermined behavior but not documented, if the [source code](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qsizegrip.cpp?h=dev#n156) is revised it will be observed:

```
Qt::Corner QSizeGripPrivate::corner() const
{
    Q_Q(const QSizeGrip);
    QWidget *tlw = qt_sizegrip_topLevelWidget(const_cast<QSizeGrip *>(q));
    const QPoint sizeGripPos = q->mapTo(tlw, QPoint(0, 0));
    bool isAtBottom = sizeGripPos.y() >= tlw->height() / 2;
    bool isAtLeft = sizeGripPos.x() <= tlw->width() / 2;
    if (isAtLeft)
        return isAtBottom ? Qt::BottomLeftCorner : Qt::TopLeftCorner;
    else
        return isAtBottom ? Qt::BottomRightCorner : Qt::TopRightCorner;
}
```

Where it is observed that the sizeGrip is placed in the upper part if it is in the upper part of the window, and this is the cause of the behavior that it observes.

The workaround is to overwrite the paintEvent method of QSizeGrip:

**PySide2:**

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class SizeGrip(QtWidgets.QSizeGrip):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionSizeGrip()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        opt.corner = QtCore.Qt.BottomRightCorner
        self.style().drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_SizeGrip, opt, painter, self)

class TestWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self , parent=None):
        super(TestWidget , self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins( 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 )
        frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        frame.setMinimumHeight( 100 )
        grip = SizeGrip(self)
        grip.setStyleSheet('''QSizeGrip { 
            image: url(dots.png);
        }''')
        layout.addWidget(frame)
        layout.addWidget(grip , 0 , QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignRight )

class TestApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(parent)
        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(centralWidget)
        for _ in range(3):
            layout.addWidget(TestWidget())
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.show()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = TestApp();
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**PySide:**

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class SizeGrip(QtGui.QSizeGrip):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        opt = QtGui.QStyleOptionSizeGrip()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        opt.corner = QtCore.Qt.BottomRightCorner
        self.style().drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_SizeGrip, opt, painter, self)

class TestWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self , parent=None):
        super(TestWidget , self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins( 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 )
        frame = QtGui.QFrame()
        frame.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        frame.setMinimumHeight( 100 )
        grip = SizeGrip(self)
        grip.setStyleSheet('''QSizeGrip { 
            image: url(dots.png);
        }''')
        grip.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.SplitVCursor)
        layout.addWidget(frame)
        layout.addWidget(grip , 0 , QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignRight )

class TestApp(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(parent)
        centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(centralWidget)
        for _ in range(3):
            layout.addWidget(TestWidget())
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.show()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = TestApp();
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]